# How to specify to not allow any data backup with android:dataExtractionRules?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My current Android application targets 12 and higher.

I do not want to allow backup of any type and currently have these manifest settings:

```xml
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

However the `android:allowBackup="false"` setting gives the following warning now:

> The attribute android:allowBackup is deprecated from Android 12 and higher and may be removed in future versions. Consider adding the attribute android:dataExtractionRules specifying an @xml resource which configures cloud backups and device transfers on Android 12 and higher.

I've looked at the examples for `android:dataExtractionRules` xml and none of them show how to configure the equivalent of `allowBackup="false"`.

What am I missing?

Is it possible to achieve `allowBackup="false"` with the use of  `android:dataExtractionRules` xml?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Add [`dataExtractionRules`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#dataExtractionRules) attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml file with a reference to **data_extraction_rules.xml** file:

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    ...>
```

Then, exclude all possible domains for cloud backups and [d2d](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#backup-restore) transfers, update or create a file **app/src/main/res/xml/data_extraction_rules.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data-extraction-rules>
    <cloud-backup>
        <exclude domain="root" />
        <exclude domain="file" />
        <exclude domain="database" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
        <exclude domain="external" />
    </cloud-backup>
    <device-transfer>
        <exclude domain="root" />
        <exclude domain="file" />
        <exclude domain="database" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
        <exclude domain="external" />
    </device-transfer>
</data-extraction-rules>
```

The `dataExtractionRules` attribute [is available](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#backup-restore) for API 31 (Android 12) and higher. Keep `allowBackup` and `fullBackupContent` attributes for Android versions before API 31.

> **Note** to maybe silence "`Attribute dataExtractionRules is only used in API level 31 and higher (current min is 19)`" warning, with `tools:targetApi="s"` attribute as well (because older platforms simply ignore manifest-attributes they don't support, and the warning is useless).

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#xml-include-exclude) say "If you specify an `<include>` element, the system no longer includes any files by default and backs up only the files specified". Did anybody try smth like `<device-transfer><include domain="" tools:ignore="FullBackupContent" /></device-transfer>`?

Comment: *`domain` — Specifies the location of resource. Valid values for this attribute include the following: `root`, `file`, `database`, `sharedpref`, `external`.* I am not sure the empty value is a valid one. [The docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#xml-include-exclude) don't specify behavior for an empty value.

Comment: We don't need to specify the exact path?? for example, "<exclude domain="sharedpref" path="here" />???? If we don't need to specify the exact path, does it exclude everything in that domain?

Comment: @CodingBruceLee this is a great question-- there's nothing said about what happens w/o a path, so would a better answer look like: <full-backup-content>
    <exclude
        domain="sharedpref"
        path="." />
    <exclude
        domain="database"
        path="." />
    <exclude
        domain="file"
        path="./" />
    <exclude
        domain="external"
        path="./" />
    <exclude
        domain="root"
        path="./" />
</full-backup-content>

Comment: Also, I don't see anywhere in the docs that "false" is legit for fullBackupContent. It is meant to point to an xml file, but from a quick look at the source may still work if "false" (or any string not pointing to parsable xml resource file) is put there.  See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/backup/FullBackup.java#495

Comment: @fattire, good point, there is a [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fullBackupContent) that says it can be boolean. IDE also shows possible values as `boolean` or `reference` (when I open Quick Documentation, Ctrl + Q).

Comment: @vadik good catch.  I didn't see that somehow, but looks like "false" is valid.  now I wonder if the path is needed too in the rules... guess I could look at the source for that too but would be best to comply with the dox if it's specified.  I kist don't see path as being listed as optional (ie, not in [brackets])

Comment: After adding data extraction rules file, I was getting an error in Android studio about missing resource in base folder (or something). To resolve, I had to restart Android studio.

Comment: You fixed it for me. The Android docs say write it `android:dataExtractionRules="backup_rules.xml"`, but that kept failing to build. Your way of writing it, `android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/backup_rules"` with the `"@xml/` in the front works

Answer (score 6):

An important question raised in the comments section of the great answer given by **@Vadik Sirekanyan** was whether or not using an `<exclude>` element with only the `domain` property would exclude everything in that domain.

Having read through the docs myself, an important point is mentioned in the **XML config syntax** section which states:

> Each `<include>` and `<exclude>` element must include the following two attributes:
> `domain`
> ...
> `path`

So, I wouldn't omit the path just to be safe.

However, an important point in the `path` section is given which I think answers the discussion point raised in the above comments:

> - If you specify a directory, then the rule applies to all files in the directory and recursive subdirectories.

Therefore, I think the following setup for the `data extraction rules` file would mimic the behaviour of `allowBackup=false`, by excluding everything in the domain's root and subdirectories from being backed-up:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data-extraction-rules>
    <cloud-backup>
        <exclude domain="root" path="." />
        <exclude domain="file" path="." />
        <exclude domain="database" path="." />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="." />
        <exclude domain="external"  path="."/>
    </cloud-backup>
    <device-transfer>
        <exclude domain="root" path="."/>
        <exclude domain="file" path="."/>
        <exclude domain="database" path="."/>
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
        <exclude domain="external" path="."/>
    </device-transfer>
</data-extraction-rules>
```

I hope this additional info helps support the above answer :)

Comment: What does "." represent in path?

Comment: The current directory