# how to specify to not backup default sharedPreference and database with android:dataExtractionRules?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-room

I want to not backup sharedPref as those contains login info. I'm using below code to not allow backup for API > android12.

```
 <cloud-backup>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
    <exclude domain="database" />
</cloud-backup>
<device-transfer>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
    <exclude domain="database" />
</device-transfer>
```

Is this enough to prevent backing up of default sharedPref and any room db?

What is the best way / what else should I do to prevent that backup?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add

```
<application
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
tools:targetApi="s">
```

The data extraction rules must be

```
<data-extraction-rules>
<cloud-backup>
    <exclude domain="database" />
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
</cloud-backup>
<device-transfer>
    <exclude domain="database" />
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
</device-transfer>
```

Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365809/how-to-specify-to-not-allow-any-data-backup-with-androiddataextractionrules-and) might help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31932899)

Comment: @TikTaZ: Your point is correct, I've edited the answer.