# Cannot resolve symbol '@xml/data_extraction_rules'

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have been working on an android app for some time now, and today when I have finished working and fixing all the errors.
After running clean project and rebuild project I am getting this error.

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\mypc\AndroidStudioProjects\BudgetTracker\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource xml/data_extraction_rules (aka com.myapp.budgettracker:xml/data_extraction_rules) not found.

C:\Users\mypc\AndroidStudioProjects\BudgetTracker\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource xml/backup_rules (aka com.myapp.budgettracker:xml/backup_rules) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

I am getting a red line in my `AndroidManifest.xml` for this line:
`android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/*data_extraction_rules*"`

I am unable to understand the reason behind this, if it is related to binding or imports, then I don't have any error currently on anything like that.
I have done fixing all the errors except for this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365809/how-to-specify-to-not-allow-any-data-backup-with-androiddataextractionrules

Comment: Why the * on android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/*data_extraction_rules*" ? Shouldn't it be android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules" ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating 2 files:
res/xml/backup_rules.xml and
res/xml/data_extraction_rules.xml

These files should have some content as described here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#include-exclude-android-12